# Method of ordered selection to approach ways to form a committee question

Tags: combinatorics

The following is a problem from A First Course in Probability by Sheldon Ross.

> A committee of 5 is to be selected from a group of 6 men and 9 women.
> If the selection is made randomly, what is the probability that the
> committee consists of 3 men and 2 women?

I know how to do this problem by the approach of unordered selection, which looks at how many ways to pick 3 men from 6 men ("6 choose 3") and how  many ways to choose 2 women from 9 women ("9 choose 2") and the total number of ways to choose 5 people from 15 of them ("15 choose 5"). The answer will simply be

$\frac{\binom{6}{3} \binom{9}{2}}{15 \choose 5} = \frac{240}{1001}$

However, suppose I take the approach of ordering my selections. I choose the men and women one after another. Maybe, I choose the 3 men first followed by the two women. The number of ways to do this ordered selection is $6\times 5 \times 4 \times 9 \times 8$. I know that by doing this ordered selection, the selection "Man A, Man B, Man C, Woman A, Woman B" would be counted differently from "Man B, Man A, Man C, Woman A, Woman B". The expression $6\times 5 \times 4 \times 9 \times 8$ will count all ordered selections where 3 men are chosen before 2 women. However, this ordered selection chooses all 3 men first followed by 2 women, so for example, it would not count the ordered selections "Man A, Woman A, Man B, Woman B, Man C" or "Woman A, Man A, Woman B, Man B, Man C". Thus, there is a need to multiply by the number of ways to permute 5 objects where 2 of them are of the same kind and 3 of them are of another same kind: $\frac{5!}{2!3!}$.

Finally, we divide by the total number of ways to perform such ordered selections of 5 people from 15 people, which is $15 \times 14 \times 13 \times 12 \times 11$. This yields the the same answer as the method of doing the unordered selections. I want to ask if my reasoning above is correct. Initially, I found it hard to convince myself that the right factor to multiply by is $\frac{5!}{2!3!}$, instead of just $5!$. Because I kept on thinking that the 5 people chosen were distinct objects because different people cannot be considered the same objects. However, later I realised that in our orderings, we are only interested in their identity as either man or woman, so different men can be treated as the same objects and likewise for the different women.

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct. You are right in multiplying $\frac{5!}{2!3!}$ instead of $5!$ since when you deal with each case, you care about order. If you want, you can instead multiply $5!$ but not care about order when choosing the men (where you would divide by $3!$) and women (where you would divide by $2!$) and still get the same answer. When you put it this way, it seems more clear that order is really irrelevant to the problem as a whole, which is why the first approach is especially simple.

Comment: @Haran I see, thanks!